# Does delta has any query which gives full details on any table?

Tags: delta-lake, delta-live-tables

I am trying to find a sql query for delta table which can give full meta data info on all the columns any delta table.

I tried `describe table mh_test.using_delta` etc but which gives only column name and type, nothing more than that.
Like Nullability, default value, auto increment etc